# Factory pattern with many conditions

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose I have 100 types of objects to be created and for that I have exposed a factory to create these objects. For the creation of these objects, I have 100's of `if, else if`.

In these kind of scenarios where many types of objects are to be created (of course you want to create one object per class), is there a better creational pattern?

Comment: If you can group the classes further, you could use an *Abstract Factory*. Also, If you want only one object per class, use *Singleton*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there's a single criteria by which you choose which class to instantiate, you can create a `Map<CriteriaType,Class>` which maps a criteria to the class that should be instantiated.

Then, your 100 if else-ifs would be reduced to a single `map.get(criteria).newInstace()`.

If you have multiple criteria, you can try to arrange them in a hierarchy, and then you can have a multi-dimensional map, such as `Map<CriteriaType1,Map<CriteriaType2,Class>>`. Then you'll have to go down the hierarchy to find the class to be instantiated.